# How to join two tables in SQL Server with multiple select

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

How to join two tables on multi select

```
select * from (
SELECT     u.NM_UNIT, p.KODE_UPT, COUNT(p.NOMOR_AJU) AS jml, p.STATUS as KODE
FROM         m_upt AS u INNER JOIN
                  t_ppk AS p ON u.KD_UNIT = p.KODE_UPT
GROUP BY u.NM_UNIT, p.KODE_UPT, p.STATUS
) as a
```

and

```
select * from (
SELECT KODE, URAIAN, KETERANGAN
FROM m_tabel
where KETERANGAN='status'
 ) as b
```

It's join on `KODE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much exactly as you'd expect. You even already have the syntax prepared. Check out [Sub Queries](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213252(v=sql.80).aspx) out on MSDN.

```
SELECT * FROM 

( SELECT u.NM_UNIT, p.KODE_UPT, COUNT(p.NOMOR_AJU) AS jml, p.STATUS as KODE 
 FROM m_upt AS u 
 INNER JOIN 
    t_ppk AS p ON u.KD_UNIT = p.KODE_UPT 
 GROUP BY u.NM_UNIT, p.KODE_UPT, p.STATUS ) as a
 INNER JOIN 
   ( SELECT KODE, URAIAN, KETERANGAN 
     FROM m_tabel  
     WHERE KETERANGAN='status' ) as b ON b.KODE = A.KODE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select * from ( SELECT u.NM_UNIT, p.KODE_UPT, COUNT(p.NOMOR_AJU) AS jml, 
    p.STATUS as KODE FROM m_upt AS u INNER JOIN t_ppk AS p ON u.KD_UNIT = p.KODE_UPT 
    GROUP BY u.NM_UNIT, p.KODE_UPT, p.STATUS ) as a 

    inner join 

   select * from ( SELECT KODE, URAIAN, KETERANGAN FROM m_tabel where 
   KETERANGAN='status' ) as b  on a.Kode=b.Kode
```